# VBA : Set Range from Cell Function

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use Excel VBA to create a Range variable that is one column to the right of `sourcerange`.

```
Dim targetRange as Range
Dim sourcerange as range

Set sourceRange = range("B1:B2") 'Works

Set targetRange = Range(cells(sourceRange.row, sourceRange.Column + 1)) 'does not work

Set targetRange = Range(Cells(2, 2)) 'does not work
```

Can anyone help explain why it is not working?

Answer (score 5):

Use

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim targetRange As Range, sourcerange As Range
    Set sourcerange = Range("B1:B2") 'Works
    Set targetRange = sourcerange.Offset(0, 1)
    Debug.Print targetRange.Address
End Sub
```

Comment: Well that was a quite a bit simpler than my suggestion. Clever thinking :-)

Comment: Note that `Set sourcerange = Range("B1:B2") ` will always be referring to the activesheet.

Comment: Or just use a single line (with an explicit sheet reference): `Set targetRange = Activesheet.Range("B1:B2").Offset(0, 1)`

Comment: @ThunderFrame - I just tried to modify the line where OP was not able to get the desired result. But you are right, this will refer to activesheet and can be written in a single line as mentioned by you.

Comment: @Mrig The volatile nature of the worksheet function matters when used in a formula, but why do you think it matters in the VBA? It's a method being explicitly called against a Range object, not as a worksheet function.

Comment: @ThunderFrame - Ah! valid point. UDF is not volatile. It's kind of become a habit to mention it whenever I use them. Note removed. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean something like this?

```
Dim sourceColumn As Long
Dim firstRow As Long
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim sourceRange As Range
Dim targetRange As Range

'Set source column number, and first + last row
sourceColumn = 2
firstRow = 1
lastRow = 3

'Set the source range, using the variables
Set sourceRange = Range(Cells(firstRow, sourceColumn), Cells(lastRow, sourceColumn))

'Likewise, set the target range, but using column number + 1
Set targetRange = Range(Cells(firstRow, sourceColumn + 1), Cells(lastRow, sourceColumn + 1))
```

Comment: Might want some error handling for when the `sourceRange` refers to the last column.

Comment: I agree that this is a slightly over-simplified example. It might also be worth to specify which workbook and sheet to use. It was primarily thought as a concept, which works in the simpler cases :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have to always refer to the sheet the range owns to and even if the range contains only one cell, setting a starting and an ending cell.

```
Set targetRange = YourSheet.Range(YourSheet.Cells(sourceRange.row, sourceRange.Column),YourSheet.Cells(sourceRange.row, sourceRange.Column+1))
```